# Laravel array inputs - htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I get the following error whenever I sumbit the form having inputs as an array.

[image]

The problem only occurs when I submit the form.

this how my input array is :

[image]

Comment: `old('type')` is array, you should get the first value of it an manually populate the input.

Comment: name="type[]" should be name="type" if there is only one. If there is multiple, then it is an array and you should treat each value after submit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are passing the input as a type of array.  htmlentities() only works on string type.
This

```
<td><input type="text" name="type[]" value="{{ old('type') }}" class="form-control"></td>
```

Should be

```
<td><input type="text" name="type" value="{{ old('type.0') }}" class="form-control"></td>
```

The type.0 will return only the first item in the array.